# Are technical-issue questions about handheld games acceptable?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

I have a question about why both my pokemon x game and pokemon y game will no longer allow me to connect to my router (for both the wonder gift torchic and for GTS), but I am not sure if [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) can apply to problems with routers, or with handhelds, because it seems to mostly be about actual bugs with a game itself, usually on a computer. I can't ask it on super user either, because they have no 3DS tag and I doubt they would appreciate questions that do not apply to computers themselves. Can I ask tech issue questions about a 3DS and a router here, even though it does not relate directly to the game?

Comment: If it helps, I have totally asked questions like this, and gotten good help here! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you may.  Connecting a gaming device to a network falls under *Game-specific hardware and utilities*.  As you've pointed out, the people at SuperUser may not know what settings to check on a 3DS, while people here will.

The technical-issues tag is not required.  All the other questions we have regarding gaming devices and routers are simply tagged with the device in question.

Comment: So it should just be tagged [tag:3ds] [tag:networking]?

Comment: Sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: Well, the question's up and I haven't been smitten by dozens of angry stackers, so I guess I have you to thank for that :)

Comment: @TheUgly - We're never angry, just efficient :). Don't be afraid of tagging things - you seem to have a pretty good grasp already, and if someone sees an issue, they'll retag it for you.